# PHP + MySQL multi DB website to single DB website with prefixes.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, database

I have a website in PHP which uses multiple MySQL tables and switches between them with the mysql_select_db function.

```
    DB1 (table1, table2, table3)
    DB2 (table1, table2)
```

The final hosting unfortunately supports only one single database. So I thought of a system which replaces the mysql_select_db functions with a custom mysql_switch_prefix function which stores a string that will be used as a prefix for all table names in following query's.

```
    DB (DB1_table1, DB1_table2, DB1_table3, DB2_table1, DB2_table2)
```

Next I will use a custom mysql_query function that replaces all table names with table names prefixed with the 'db_prefix' variable.

```
    SELECT * FROM `table1` -> SELECT * FROM `DB1_table1`
```

Is there a way (or a regular expression) to replace all table names in a SQL statement by table names prefixed with a variable?

Comment: Now if only MySQL had `schema`s, and not just `database`s, I'd recommend dumping them in each in a seperate `schema`.  Is there some reason that they _have_ to be prefixed (do you have table name collisions)?  Should the tables be renamed (to something more descriptive or distinctive)?  Otherwise, I'd say just let the names stay the same, and save yourself the hassle.

Comment: The problem is that you can have table names in quite a few places in and SQL query, not only after a `from`. A regex _may_ be built, but it will more than probably miss cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the table names and put them into a PHP array.

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM [DB name]")
while($tableNames = mysql_fetch_row($result)){...}
```

Then create a loop, and do something like this:

```
mysql_query("RENAME TABLE" . $tableNames[$i] . "TO [prefix]" . tableNames[$i]);
```

Here's the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html), for the "RENAME..." query.